# Should we install beadboard paneling or countertop first?

Tags: kitchens, backsplash, countertops

We are planning to install bead board paneling to our kitchen back splash, and new Formica for the counter tops.  Which product should be installed first, and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are advantages to doing it either way.

If you put the paneling up first, and slid the counter top back so it overlaps the panel a bit, you'll get a very nice looking edge if properly caulked.

BUT, doing it this way runs the risk of water running down the back splash, and running behind the counter, creating a rot/mould risk on the cabinetry underneath (particularly if the caulk fails).

If the paneling goes over the counter top, you mitigate the water risk, but it's going to be a lot harder to get a good looking edge.

Comment: This was my concern. Caulking the bead board (if placed on top of counter) might look messy, but beats having moisture running down the back. The solution might be to put a narrow piece of trim over the caulk.  Thank you for your insights.

Comment: I was thinking about the trim as well. It might get in the way.

Comment: I would have concerns about long term exposure of the wood to sink splash.

Comment: A piece of shoe molding placed over the properly caulked seam between the counter and bead board should create the nice looking finish you want without taking up any serious space.  Plus, caulking it as well adds an additional layer of protection for water leakage.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments...I hadn't considered the sink splash issue, and may need to rethink this.